# What are the standard dimensions for cabinet making?

Tags: cabinetry

Sorry, I don't know what this is called so doing the best to describe it....

I am building a custom built-in cabinet.

I want to know if there is a standard height of the outside finished face frame (specifically the horizontal rail above the toe kick)

This measurment would be from the floor of the cabinet to the top of the horizontal face frame rail?  A portion of this horizontal rail is typically covered by the bottom of the cabinet door.

Comment: Typically you'd go searching on google images or shopping malls to see which style/design you like and measure from it.

Answer (score 2):

The floor of the cabinet is 3-1/2" toe kick space + width of face frame stock", Top of the cabinet is 34-1/2" allowing for a 1-1/2" countertop to come to a 36" height above floor. Disclaimer - In the US

Comment: Also, countertop height is only "normally" 38", that is, there is no formal standard to which it must conform. Custom countertops can be what ever height the client wants. In the case of short or tall folk, the difference can be considerable.